# How to add barButtonItem to ToolBar

Tags: swift, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

How could I convert this code to have the button appear in the toolbar? :

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "onEditButtonTapped:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

then write the action function likes this,

```
    func onEditButtonTapped(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "btnClicked:"), animated: true)


  //adding function to bar button

    func btnClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
     {
        //your code here
     }
```